# Issue with argument passing in javascript

Tags: javascript, arguments

Here is my function :

```
function findTextFromValue(source, id){
    var returnValue = '';
    //source = [{value:1, text:"Champagne"},{value:2, text:"Vallée de la Loire"},    {value:3, text:"Bordelais"},{value:4, text:"Sud-Ouest"},{value:5, text:"Languedoc-Roussillon"},{value:6, text:"Lorraine"},{value:7, text:"Alsace"},{value:8, text:"Jura"},{value:9, text:"Bourgogne"},{value:11, text:"Savoie"},{value:12, text:"Vallée du Rhône"},{value:13, text:"Provence"},{value:14, text:"Corse"},{value:15, text:"Coteaux du Lyonnais"},{value:16, text:"Bugey"}];
    //alert(source);
    $.each( source, function(key, value) {
        if(value.value == id){
            returnValue = value.text;
            return false;/* BREAK EACH ITERATION*/
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}
```

When the source is set inside the function, everything works perfectly.
When the source is passed via function argument, I get a

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
```

The hardcoded array is the array I've copy/paste from the alert, so it's supposed to be exactly the same. What am I missing?

**SOLUTION :**

```
source = eval(source);
```

**BETTER SOLUTION**

eval is evil (I've been told ...) The good answer is :

```
source = JSON.parse(source);
```

for those who have this error :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'
```

it means you JSON array does not contain double quotes. Example :

```
[{"value":"1", "text":"Champagne"}, ...]
```

Comment: Are you sure you pass an array and not, for example, a JSON string ?

Comment: To learn more about your source, don't use `alert`. Use `console.log(source, typeof source);` and open the console (F12).

Comment: Show us an example where it fails!

Comment: source was string and not array ! thanks for quik answer. See details on accepted solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost certainly passing a string to the function instead of an actual array. I say this because the following code reproduces the exact error:

```
var s = '[{value:1, text:"Champagne"},{value:2, text:"Vallée de la Loire"},    {value:3, text:"Bordelais"},{value:4, text:"Sud-Ouest"},{value:5, text:"Languedoc-Roussillon"},{value:6, text:"Lorraine"},{value:7, text:"Alsace"},{value:8, text:"Jura"},{value:9, text:"Bourgogne"},{value:11, text:"Savoie"},{value:12, text:"Vallée du Rhône"},{value:13, text:"Provence"},{value:14, text:"Corse"},{value:15, text:"Coteaux du Lyonnais"},{value:16, text:"Bugey"}]'

$.each(s,function(key, value) {
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7VUgc/ (Watch the console for the error)

Comment: Indeed ! It was a string instead of an array ! It works doing : source = eval(source);

Comment: @hugsbrugs - [be careful with javascript eval](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)